# How to download large file generated by jsreports-core

Tags: javascript, jsreport

Upon receiving a request from a client and I am generating a pdf using jsreport core and then send the file to the client as such:

```
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.pdf');
  jsreport.render(form).then(response => response.stream.pipe(res));
```

Now I want to download the file on the client side by taking resulting string from the request and converting it to a blob and then converting the blob to URL how ever the resulting file I'm getting is empty and I believe it is because the resulting url generated from from the pdf string is too long...Does any body have any suggestions for downloading the resulting file in the browser using javascript?

Answer (score 3):

from your client side/front-end code you will need to call the jsreport server by doing a form based post request, which is needed by the browser to start a download dialog.

you can put this utility code ([taken from the jsreport browser sdk source code](https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-browser-client-dist)) somewhere in your own code.

```
function download (serverUrl, filename, request) {
  var requestValues = Object.assign({}, request)

  requestValues.options = requestValues.options || {}
  requestValues.options['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=' + filename

  return render(serverUrl, requestValues)
}

function render (serverUrl, request) {
  var frameName = placeholder || '_blank'
  var mapForm = document.createElement('form')
  mapForm.target = frameName
  mapForm.id = new Date().getTime()
  mapForm.method = 'POST'
  mapForm.action = serverUrl

  function addInput (form, name, value) {
    var input = document.createElement('input')
    input.type = 'hidden'
    input.name = name
    input.value = value
    form.appendChild(input)
  }

  function addBody (path, body) {
    if (body === undefined) {
      return
    }

    for (var key in body) {
      if (isObject(body[key])) {
        // somehow it skips empty array for template.scripts, this condition fixes that
        if (body[key] instanceof Array && body[key].length === 0) {
          addInput(mapForm, path + '[' + key + ']', [])
        }
        addBody(path + '[' + key + ']', body[key])
      } else {
        if (body[key] !== undefined && !(body[key] instanceof Array)) {
          addInput(mapForm, path + '[' + key + ']', body[key])
        }
      }
    }
  }

  addBody('template', request.template)

  if (request.options != null) {
    addBody('options', request.options)
  }

  if (request.data) {
    addBody('data', request.data)
  }

  var headers = {}
  headers['host-cookie'] = document.cookie
  addBody('headers', headers)

  document.body.appendChild(mapForm)

  function submit (i) {
    if (i > 10) {
      return console.log('Unable to submit render form.')
    }
    try {
      mapForm.submit()
      mapForm.outerHTML = ''
    } catch (e) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        submit(i + 1)
      }, 50)
    }
  }

  submit(0)
}
```

and then use it like this (of course you will need to update `http://localhost:5488/your-report-route` to the real url where your server is working).

```
download('http://localhost:5488/your-report-route', 'newfile.pdf', {
  template: {
    // your options here
  },
  data: {
    // your data here
  }
})
```